# Duplicated stax classes

Tags: java, json, maven, stax

I want to ban duplicated classes from a java 8 maven project and I don't know how to resolve the following "conflict"

Duplicate classes found:

```
  Found in:                                         
    javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile     
    stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile                 
  Duplicate classes:                                
    javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.class           
    javax/xml/stream/StreamFilter.class             
    javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete.class                                       
    javax/xml/stream/util/StreamReaderDelegate.class
    javax/xml/stream/events/StartDocument.class     
    javax/xml/stream/EventFilter.class              
    javax/xml/stream/XMLEventWriter.class           
    javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamConstants.class       
    javax/xml/stream/events/EntityDeclaration.class 
    javax/xml/stream/events/ProcessingInstruction.class                                                  
    javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.class          
    javax/xml/stream/Location.class                 
    javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$1.class          
    javax/xml/stream/events/DTD.class               
    javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamException.class       
    javax/xml/stream/util/XMLEventAllocator.class   
    javax/xml/stream/events/Characters.class        
    javax/xml/stream/events/Namespace.class
    javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.class
    javax/xml/stream/events/NotationDeclaration.class
    javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinder.class
    javax/xml/stream/util/XMLEventConsumer.class
    javax/xml/stream/events/XMLEvent.class
    javax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory.class
    javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.class
    javax/xml/stream/events/EndDocument.class
    javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.class
    javax/xml/stream/events/EntityReference.class
    javax/xml/stream/util/EventReaderDelegate.class
    javax/xml/stream/XMLReporter.class
    javax/xml/stream/XMLResolver.class
    javax/xml/stream/events/EndElement.class
    javax/xml/stream/FactoryConfigurationError.class
    javax/xml/stream/events/Comment.class
    javax/xml/stream/events/Attribute.class
    javax/xml/stream/FactoryFinder.class
    javax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory.class
```

One stax jar comes from jersey-json

```
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.19.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
```

The other from poi

```
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.11:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
```

I guess it is safe to remove that `stax-api` dependency from poi since it is provided since JDK 1.6 or so

However that jersey part is suspicious too, why on earth is it called `jersey-json` when it wants to work with stax?

This project actually uses only json

What do you suggest?

Comment: I believe the Jersey JSON parser/formatter can use JAXB annotations to specify how the JSON should look, that's why it depends on JAXB.

Comment: @Andreas this is by no means a duplicate! Of course the solution is to exclude one dependency but the question is which.

Comment: It sure is a duplicate, because you said *"I don't know how to resolve the following "conflict""* and *"What do you suggest?"*, so I suggested excluding a transitive dependency and linked to duplicate showing how. If you already knew that, perhaps you should have said so in the question. --- Which one? The older one.

Comment: @Andreas sinece stax-api is not always backward compatible this can't be the ultimate solution thats why i was asking `However that jersey part is suspicious too, why on earth is it called jersey-json when it wants to work with stax?`

Comment: I though I answered that in my first comment, but let me say it a different way: Jersey JSON doesn't want to work with StAX, it wants to work with JAXB, most likely because it wants to use the JAXB annotations, e.g. `@XmlElement` to specify JSON field name.